# Drawing a tree and printing it as a PDF

Tags: java, swing, pdf, pdfbox, jtree

Currently I have a report generated with Apache PDFBox. I need to generate a tree and attach this tree as a page to that PDF report. Is it possible to generate a tree and create a PDF with Jtree? If not what would be the best strategy?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution I found might be not that fancy, but it works. What I did was drawing a JTree in a JFrame (it doesn't display in the screen) then I get a buffered image of the window. And finally paste that image in the PDF using one of the built-in methods of PDFBox. I have uploaded the project on github in case you want to check it out. https://github.com/LuisR-jpg/Directory_Tree